# A while infinte cycle actually stops using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, while-loop, pthreads, do-while

I'm new to C and I am trying to learn. I'm trying to implement multithreading in my program, but I'm having problems. The program (and the threads) should be going on running in a infinite loop, but actually the programs stops after few seconds. What can I do for having the program running forever? Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void *func(void *threadid){
    while (1)
    {
        /* do stuff, but the program terminates after that thread does few cycles */
    }
}

int main(){
    #define NUM_THREADS 800
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc, i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, func, (void *)i);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("Error to create thread, #%d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your main thread exits, the program terminates (and so do the threads). If you want your program to never end, you should add a `while(1);` at the end of you main while loop.

Note that this is not how to do it properly, your threads should have an end, and the master thread should wait for all the threads to be done, before exiting itself.

Comment: `while(1);` is Horrible Advice.  `while(1) { sleep(1000); }` would be OK, but not the best advice. The best advice, would be to `join()` all of the child threads. The `while...sleep` pattern says, "I do not want the process to terminate." That's a reasonable thing to say, but using `join()` says more. `join()` says, "I do not want this process to terminate _because_ I want the child threads to continue running."

Comment: Thanks, It works, but now I'm wondering, why adding a while(1); at the end of a while(1) cycle let the threads continue and the only while(1) that I created before does not? What does this extra while(1) do exactly? Why only one while isn't enough?

Comment: 1st, do the trick with the sleep, I forgot to put it in my answer, but it's very important in order to spare your CPU's resources.
Then, you need to understand that you have a "master" thread, which is the one creating all the other threads you have. As soon as this "master" thread exists, so does your complete program. The new while loop i advice you to create is to block the "master thread" ;)